# How to call Session Storage in View.py

Tags: python, django, session, view, session-storage

It goes without saying that I am fairly new to Django so any help is much appreciated.

I am trying to access variable 'user_id' that I stored in session Storage in view.py.

**view.py:**

```
class ProfileOrders(View):
template_name = 'landingpages/profile-orders.html' 

def get(self, request):
    customer_identity = self.request.session.get('user_id');
    first_entry = CompleteOrderList.objects.get(customer_id = customer_identity, order_id='9d41cf4b-b606-461c-bc4e-f7363984782b');
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'first_entry': first_entry})
```

but I get an error: "CompleteOrderList matching query does not exist."
because **self.request.session.get('user_id') returns 'none'**. On error page I can see:

> kwargs {'customer_id': None, 'order_id': '9d41cf4b-b606-461c-bc4e-f7363984782b'}

Instead of using "self.request.session.get('user_id')" if I type actual value like:

> customer_identity = 'XXXX'

I can see the query works. I cannot hardcode this value but not sure how to pull that 'XXXX' from session storage in view.py. Thanks in advance for your help!

---

*I have another question in mind after fixing this:*

Actually **order_id** won't be hard coded either and the query

> all_entries = CompleteOrderList.objects.get(customer_id = customer_identity)

would be returning multiple rows. I need to figure out a way to put these in an array type of thing and use it in template like

```
<div class="container_order">
    <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-3x">{{ all_entries.first_row }}</i>
</div>
<div class="container_order">
    <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-3x">{{ all_entries.second_row }}</i>
</div> 
...
```

any suggestion/help with this is also much appreciated. Hopefully I am not asking too much. I don't want be seen as asking others write the whole code but I spent hours to figure out how to do this and failed miserably! Hopefully experienced django users can share this valuable information with me!

Thanks!

@Daniel Roseman 
It is set in another template as shown below and I confirmed that **user_id** exists with the correct value in SessionStorage by investigating through chrome dev tools.

```
if (idToken) {
      lock.getProfile(idToken, function (err, profile) {
        if (err) {
          return alert('There was an error getting the profile: ' + err.message);
        }
        // Display user information
        $('#name').text(profile.name);
        $('#email').text(profile.email);
        $('#user_id').text(profile.user_id);  
        $('#nickname').text(profile.nickname); 
        sessionStorage.setItem('user_id', profile.user_id);
      });
    };
```

Comment: Well it sounds like the ID isn't in the session at all. How was it supposed to get there in the first place? Show the code that should set it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for looking into it. Added the code that saves the user_id to storage. Also checked from console what "sessionStorage.getItem('user_id');" returns on that page and I can see the correct value is returned there too.

Comment: You're confusing two completely separate things here. Browser-side sessionStorage has nothing at all to do with the Django session.

Comment: I see. What I am trying to do is pull the value from browser-side but didn't realize 'self.request.session.get()' uses another type of session. Any hints on how to pull it from browser? or what would be the better design?

Comment: You can't "pull" it from the browser. The only thing you can do is to get your JS to send it to the server in some way, eg via Ajax.